# Django queryset optimization with prefetch_related

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project based on Django 1.11, and I'm trying to optimize database access with `prefetch_related`, here is what I'm facing:

I have some model definitions(simplified):

```
class D(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField()


class A(models.Model):
    foo = models.FloatField()


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    d = models.ForeignKey(D, related_name='bs')

    # Some fields are identical to C 
    foo = models.CharField()

    # A special field 
    bar1 = models.FileField()


class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    d = models.ForeignKey(D, related_name='cs')

    # Some fields are identical to B
    foo = models.CharField()

    # A special field 
    bar2 = models.FloatField()
```

[image: Model Relation]

I want to retrieve some objects of `D`, when retrieving them from DB, I want to retrieve them along with all related(directly) `B` objects and `C` objects and related(indirectly) `A` objects, Currently I'm using:

```
>>> qs = D.objects.filter(foo=1)  # some queryset of D
>>> qs = qs.prefetch_related('bs__a', 'cs__a')
```

The performance is ok(compared with no `prefetch_related`), I see raw SQL queries from `django-debug-toolbar` and it looks like Django breaks the query into something like(psuedo SQL):

```
select * from D

select * from B where `d`.`id` in (ids from D)
select * from A where `A`.`id` in (ids from B)  ---> first time

select * from C where `d`.`id` in (ids from D)
select * from A where `A`.`id` in (ids from C)  ---> second time
```

But what I want is, Concat ids from B and C and result in one query to A:

```
select * from D
select * from B where `d`.`id` in (ids from D)
select * from C where `d`.`id` in (ids from D)

select * from A where `A`.`id` in (ids from B, ids from C)
```

Is this possible? If so, How? Thanks.

(Or maybe I should combine `B` and `C` result in one model by introducing a field to indicate type(B or C) and both non-shared fields from B and C now are shared, but I think this is a waste of storage, since bar2 means nothing to B and bar1 means nothing to C)